# Set Payment Method "Cash On Delivery" on Particular State Only

Tags: magento, payment, magento-1.8

I want to set "Cash On Delivery" for the site owner's State only

I know how to set For "Specified Country"

I am using Magento 1.8

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuFFy,you  doing this using magento event observer:

Create an extension and here the step:

create config.xml under :**`app/code/community/Devamitbera/Statewisecod/etc/config.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
@Author Amit Bera
@Email dev.amitbera@gmail.com
@ Website: www.amitbera.com
*/-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Devamitbera_Statewisecod>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Devamitbera_Statewisecod>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <statewisecod>
                <class>Devamitbera_Statewisecod_Model</class>
            </statewisecod>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend> <!--  run observer  event for frontend -->
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <enable_cod_for_some_state>
                        <class>statewisecod/observer</class>
                        <method>EnableCod</method>
                    </enable_cod_for_some_state>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Create observer file 
under **Observer.php** under **`app/code/community/Devamitbera/Statewisecod/Model`**

**Code  of this file:**

```
  <?php
class Devamitbera_Statewisecod_Model_Observer
{
    public function EnableCod($observer){
        $result=$observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $MethodInstance=$observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote=$observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        if($quote && $quote->getId()):
        /* If Payment method is  cashondelivery  then  conitnue  */
            if($MethodInstance->getCode()=='cashondelivery'){
                #Mage::log('Payment is Cod',null,'Cod.log',true);
                $ShippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();

                /* region_id is working when country have  
                * drop state/regions.
                */
                /* Here i  have put USA coutry new work & Washinton redion */

                #Mage::log('redion'.$ShippingAddress->getRegionId(),null,'redion.log',true);

                $CodEnableRegionIds=array(62,43);
                if(in_array($ShippingAddress->getRegionId(),$CodEnableRegionIds)):
                      $result->isAvailable=true;
                elseif(is_null($ShippingAddress->getRegionId()) && !is_null($ShippingAddress->getRegion())):
                /* This section working when State/region is not dropdown 
                 and state is dropdown
                */
                $textListRegionName=array('West bengal','Delhi');
                    if(in_array($ShippingAddress->getRegion(),$textListRegionName)){
                          $result->isAvailable=true;
                    }else{
                          $result->isAvailable=false;
                    }
                else:
                  $result->isAvailable=false;
                endif;              


                return   $result->isAvailable;
            }

        endif;


    }
}
```

create module file  `Devamitbera_Statewisecod.xml` under `app/etc/modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
@Author Amit Bera
@Email dev.amitbera@gmail.com
@ Website: www.amitbera.com
-->
<config>
    <modules>
    <Devamitbera_Statewisecod>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
        <active>true</active>
        <depends><Mage_Payment/></depends>
    </Devamitbera_Statewisecod>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here `cashondelivery` is payment method `code of cash on delivery`.... which is saved in database.

### - Edited:

**region_id** is working when country have   *drop state/regions list*.

```
if(in_array($ShippingAddress->getRegionId(),$CodEnableRegionIds)):
                      $result->isAvailable=true;
```

If  **State/region** is not **dropdown then Below logic is work**

```
elseif(is_null($ShippingAddress->getRegionId()) && !is_null($ShippingAddress->getRegion())):
$textListRegionName=array('West bengal','Delhi');
    if(in_array($ShippingAddress->getRegion(),$textListRegionName)){
      $result->isAvailable=true;
    }else{
      $result->isAvailable=false;
    }
```

Comment: what is 'code' here in "if($method->getCode()=='code')" ??

Comment: Sorry each  payment have payment code just goto app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Method see all payment method list.ex: Open Cashondelivery.php see code protected $_code  = 'cashondelivery';

Comment: if have any issue ..let me know